# How to make pagination on firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

i'm trying to make firebase paginate, it throws an error: Type ""limitToFirst"" cannot be satisfied for type "QueryConstraintType". what am i doing wrong?

`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const q = query(collection(db, "goods"), where("tags", "array-contains-any", ["Хит"]), limit(5), startAt(5))
      const documentSnapshots = await getDocs(q)
      documentSnapshots.forEach((el) => {
        console.log(el.data());
      })
    }
    getData()
  }, [])
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Given `startAt(5)` you seem to think that `startAt` takes an offset, while Firestore's pagination is actually based on a query cursor: knowing details about the specific document you want to start at.

This means that you need to pass either the `DocumentSnapshot` you want to start at, or all sorted field values and the document ID of the document you want to start at to the `startAt` operation. So [`startAt`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#startat) expects either a `DocumentSnapshot` or an array of values, and you're passing neither of those.

For more on this, I recommend checking out the Firestore documentation on [implementing pagination using query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).